# Relative path for sdcard images

Tags: android

hi I have a folder called Images on my sdCard. i.e. /mnt/sdcard/images. I am accessing these images using this code

```
private List<String> getList(){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("/mnt/sdcard/Images/a03.JPG");  
    list.add("/mnt/sdcard/Images/a02.jpg");  
    list.add("/mnt/sdcard/Images/a01.jpg");  
    return list;
}
```

howver i want to access these images instead of having all full path. like

```
    list.add("/Images/a03.JPG");
```

but i am getting read error file not found exception.
any help please.

Comment: can you explain why you need to add path of images in a arraylist?

Comment: @Raghunandan actually I am passing this arraylist to my viewpager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + PATH_SD_CARD;
public final static String PATH_SD_CARD = "/Images/";
```

And then your array list.

```
 private List<String> getList(){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(path +"a01.jpg");  
    list.add(path +"a02.jpg");  
    list.add(path +"a03.jpg");  
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use hard code paths. Use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

```
    private File[] listFile;  
    ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();  
    public void getFromSdcard()
    {
        File file= new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Images");
            if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                listFile = file.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++)
                {

                    f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

                }

            }
    }
```

Add permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Suppose your folder contains other files.

```
     String Patternjpg = ".jpg";  
     for(int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {  
     if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(Patternjpg)){
             f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
       }
       }
```

Comment: how can I pass this to viewpager

Comment: pass the arraylist to the constructor of adapter class and use the same there

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
private List<String> getList(){
  String PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/Images/";
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add(PATH + "a03.JPG");  
  list.add(PATH + "a02.jpg");  
  list.add(PATH + "a01.jpg");  
  return list;
}
```